# How to change the text returned by DisplayFor in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

In MVC, I used a `DescriptionAttribute` to change the text returned by `DisplayFor()`.

But I can't figure out how to do this in Razor Pages.

I tried:

```
[Description("Available Spots")]
public int? AvailableSpots {get; set; }
```

And I tried:

```
builder.Entity<Location>()
    .Property(m => m.AvailableSpots)
    .HasComment("Available Spots");
```

And still my column headers display as *AvailableSpots*.

It's frustrating how Core has taken away so many conveniences we had before. Does anyone know how to change the text returned by `DisplayFor()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
[Display(Name = "Available Spots")]
public int? AvailableSpots {get; set; }
```